# Prepending form name, subform name to id of zend dojo form

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, dojo, zend-form

I am using Zend Form and Dojo.  I have a whole bunch of ids that are identical.  If you look at the following code you can see my current look :

```
<dt id="addElement-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="addElement-element"> <button name="createEventForm[categoryDetail][addElement]" id="createEventForm-categoryDetail-addElement" type="button">addElement</button></dd>
```

Here is what I would like it to look like

```
<dt id="createEventForm-categoryDetail-addElement-label">&nbsp;</dt><dd id="createEventForm-categoryDetail-addElement-element"> <button name="createEventForm[categoryDetail][addElement]" id="createEventForm-categoryDetail-addElement" type="button">addElement</button></dd>
```

I want to do this as currently this created quite a few identical Ids and that is causing other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have custom IDs for elements, you need to use your own decorators.
The default DtDdWrapper returns the "standard IDs"

```
// Zend/Form/Decorator/DtDdWrapper.php line 60-61
return '<dt id="' . $elementName . '-label">&nbsp;</dt>' .
       '<dd id="' . $elementName . '-element">' . $content . '</dd>';
```

I would suggest either

- extend the class and overload the render() function or
- create and use your own, custom decorator for `Zend_Form_Element`

Answer (score 0):

You can take out fields that will be repeated into subform. Ids will be made from subform name and element name separated by dash.